# React error: web3 is not defined no-undef

Tags: reactjs, web3js

I installed web3 in a folder of react-app:

> npm install --save ethereum/web3.js

but I get a react error:

> web3 is not defined  no-undef

import Web3 from 'web3'

```
export const startMetaMask = () => {

    if (window.ethereum) {
        web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
        try {
            window.ethereum.enable().then(function() {
                
            });
        } catch (e) {}
    }
    
    else if (window.web3) {
        web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
    }
    
    else {
        alert('You have to install MetaMask !');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you installed your web3 like that:

`npm install --save ethereum/web3.js`

please check your `package.json` file to see how this library is viewed, probably it will be `ethereum/web3`. So your import should look more like that:

```js
import Web3 from 'ethereum/web3'
```

If you wanted to install web3 package from npm, you can just do it with:

`npm install --save web3`

and import like you did. According to https://www.npmjs.com/package/web3

Answer (score 0):

You should import package like this as mention in the [Documentation](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3.html)

cause it's `Named Export` not `Default export`

```
import {Web3} from 'web3';
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, it does not help